# Problem TO Fetch Database to HTML via PHP

Tags: php, html, database, fetch

I want to make the php read the data from database, and input the price into the other table. But it always not fetch the data correctly.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="english">
  <head>
    <title>exported project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />

    <style data-tag="reset-style-sheet">
      html {  line-height: 1.15;}body {  margin: 0;}* {  box-sizing: border-box;  border-width: 0;  border-style: solid;}p,li,ul,pre,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,figure,blockquote,figcaption {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}button {  background-color: transparent;}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea {  font-family: inherit;  font-size: 100%;  line-height: 1.15;  margin: 0;}button,select {  text-transform: none;}button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"] {  -webkit-appearance: button;}button::-moz-focus-inner,[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {  border-style: none;  padding: 0;}button:-moz-focus,[type="button"]:-moz-focus,[type="reset"]:-moz-focus,[type="submit"]:-moz-focus {  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;}a {  color: inherit;  text-decoration: inherit;}input {  padding: 2px 4px;}img {  display: block;}html { scroll-behavior: smooth  }
    </style>
    <style data-tag="default-style-sheet">
      html {
        font-family: Inter;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      body {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style:normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 1.15;
        color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
        background-color: var(--dl-color-gray-white);

      }
    </style>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&amp;display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&amp;display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&amp;display=swap"
      data-tag="font"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php include 'desktop6Process.php'?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <div>
      <link href="./desktop6.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <div class="desktop6-container">
        <div class="desktop6-desktop6">
          <img
            alt="Line13218"
            src="public/external/line13218-y9e.svg"
            class="desktop6-line1"
          />
          <a href="desktop4.php" class="desktop6-navlink">
            <img
              alt="overalliconsvgpersonincharge23220"
              src="public/external/overalliconsvgpersonincharge23220-zn2.svg"
              class="desktop6-overalliconsvgpersonincharge2"
            />
          </a>
          <form class="desktop6-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <div class="desktop6-container1">
              <span class="desktop6-text">14&nbsp;</span>
              <select class="desktop6-select" name="color">
                <option value="Midnight" selected="">Midnight</option>
                <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
                <option value="Starlight">Starlight</option>
              </select>
              <select class="desktop6-select1" name="capacity">
                <option value="128">128</option>
                <option value="256">256</option>
                <option value="512">512</option>
              </select>
              <button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="desktop6-button button">Add to Cart</button>
              <img
                src="public/external/iphone_14-removebg-preview%20(1)-400h.png"
                alt="image"
                class="desktop6-image"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="desktop6-container2">
              <span class="desktop6-text01">14 Plus&nbsp;</span>
              <select class="desktop6-select2" name="color">
                <option value="Midnight" selected="">Midnight</option>
                <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
                <option value="Starlight">Starlight</option>
              </select>
              <select class="desktop6-select3" name="capacity">
                <option value="128" selected="">128</option>
                <option value="256">256</option>
                <option value="512">512</option>
              </select>
              <button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="desktop6-button1 button">Add to Cart</button>
              <img
                src="public/external/14_plus_black-removebg-preview-400h.png"
                alt="image"
                class="desktop6-image1"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="desktop6-container3">
              <span class="desktop6-text02" >14 Pro&nbsp;</span>
              <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="iPhone 14 Pro">
              <select class="desktop6-select4" name="color">
                <option selected="">Color</option>
                <option value="Space Black">Space Black</option>
                <option value="Deep Purple">Deep Purple</option>
                <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
                <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
              </select>
              <select class="desktop6-select5" name="capacity">
                <option selected="">GB</option>
                <option value="128GB" >128</option>
                <option value="256GB">256</option>
                <option value="512GB">512</option>
                <option value="1TB">1TB</option>
              </select>
              <select class="desktop6-select8" name="quantity">
                <option selected="">Quantity</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
              </select>
              <button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="desktop6-button2 button">Add to Cart</button>
              <img
                src="public/external/iphone_14_pro_max-removebg-preview-400h.png"
                alt="image"
                class="desktop6-image2"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="desktop6-container4">
              <span class="desktop6-text03">14 Pro Max&nbsp;</span>
              <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="14 Pro Max">
              <select class="desktop6-select6" name="color">
                <option value="Space Black" selected="">Space Black</option>
                <option value="Deep Purple">Deep Purple</option>
                <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                <option value="Silver">SIlver</option>
              </select>
              <select class="desktop6-select7" name="capacity" >
                <option value="128" selected="">128</option>
                <option value="256">256</option>
                <option value="512">512</option>
                <option value="1TB">1TB</option>
              </select>
              <button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="desktop6-button3 button">Add to Cart</button>
              <img
                src="public/external/pngwing.com__1_-removebg-preview-500h.png"
                alt="image"
                class="desktop6-image3"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
          <a href="desktop5.php" class="desktop6-navlink1">
            <img
              alt="iconshoppingcartline23222"
              src="public/external/iconshoppingcartline23222-gz3m.svg"
              class="desktop6-iconshoppingcartline2"
            />
          </a>
          <span class="desktop6-text04"><span>iPong 14</span></span>
          <a href="desktop2.php" class="desktop6-text06"><span>SHOP</span></a>
          <img
            alt="Rectangle33251"
            src="public/external/rectangle33251-xrob-200h.png"
            class="desktop6-rectangle3"
          />
          <span class="desktop6-text08"><span>Adam, Muiz, Adzmir</span></span>
          <span class="desktop6-text10"><span>Own By</span></span>
        </div>
        <a href="index.php" class="desktop6-navlink2">
          <img
            alt="image"
            src="public/external/mesin%20logo-400w.jpg"
            class="desktop6-image4"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost"; // Change to your database server name
$username = "root"; // Change to your database username
$password = ""; // Change to your database password
$dbname = "Mesin"; // Change to your database name

// Establish the database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $productName = $_POST['product_name']; // Product name from user input
        $color = $_POST['color']; // Color from user input
        $capacity = $_POST['capacity']; // Capacity from user input
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; // Quantity from user input

        // Fetch price directly from productdata table
        $selectPrice = $conn->prepare("SELECT price FROM productdata WHERE product_name = :productName AND color = :color AND storage_capacity = :capacity");

        $selectPrice->execute(array(
            ':productName' => $productName,
            ':color' => $color,
            ':capacity' => $capacity
        ));
        
        if ($selectPrice->rowCount() > 0) {
            $price = $selectPrice->fetchColumn();
        
            if ($price !== false) {
                $insertCartData = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usercart (Username, ProductName, Color, Capacity, Price, Quantity) VALUES (:username, :productName, :color, :capacity, :price, :quantity)");
                $insertCartData->bindParam(':username', $username);
                $insertCartData->bindParam(':productName', $productName);
                $insertCartData->bindParam(':color', $color);
                $insertCartData->bindParam(':capacity', $capacity);
                $insertCartData->bindParam(':price', $price);
                $insertCartData->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
                $insertCartData->execute();
        
                header("Location: desktop5.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "Price found but not retrieved properly. Price Output: $price";
            }
        } else {
            $errorInfo = $selectPrice->errorInfo();
            echo "Failed to execute the query. Error: " . $errorInfo[2];
            echo " Query: " . $selectPrice->queryString; // Output the actual query being executed
        }
    } else {
        // Redirect the user to the login page if the session is not set
        header("Location: desktop4.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

The Database:

Database I want to insert:
[image: Database I want to insert]

Database I want to fetch price from:
[image: Database I want to fetch price from]

I want the database can send the price to the other database based on the inserted data by the user.

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing?  Is it with the SELECT part or the INSERT part?

Comment: "But it always not fetch the data correctly" - What is "correct"? Are you getting an error? Is it just not displaying as you want it to?

Comment: For your own personal notes, phpMyAdmin is **not** a database, it is a web interface that is commonly used to access a MySQL/MariaDB server. Unless you are doing something special, your code will never talk directly to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: also, you are probably talking about tables of a database and not databases per se.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. So far it's about as clear as mud.